Understanding またしても掌を返すように賛同した
Summary of 聲の形:

とある小学校に通学する硝子は聾唖者のため授業を止めることがあり、それが原因でクラス中から嫌われていた。クラスメイトの将也は執拗に硝子をいじめるが、度の過ぎた悪行が遠因してクラスにおいて吊し上げられた挙句、新たないじめの標的にされる。あまりにもあっけなく掌を返されてしまった彼を硝子は気にかけるが、結局、将也とは分かり合えず転校していった。硝子の転校後、心ないことを言った将也に対し、またしても掌を返すように賛同した担任とクラスメイトを見たことで、将也は初めて自身のクラスにある、恐ろしいほどの異常さを痛感し、硝子のために自ら行動を起こすようになる。

I have trouble with またしても掌を返すように賛同した means here. I think it means "once again, as if he (担任) suddenly switched sides, he (担任) joined classmates to bully him (将也)"? I uncertain with the meaning of 賛同した part.

Apparently, they switched sides in his favor "once again" after the girl left school. The passage doesn't say how exactly.

賛同した means to agree/support,
in this context the class bullied 将也 for bulling 硝子 but as soon as 硝子 changes schools they started to agreed and supported 将也.
When I say they I mean 担任とクラスメイト together.
硝子is disliked by the class->将也bullies硝子->(掌を返して)(担任とクラスメイト)bully将也->硝子leaves the school->(掌を返して)(担任とクラスメイト)agree with将也
